# UITextField placeholder showing up with a shadow behind UITextField.text when setting text programatically. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, inputview

I'm setting a `UITextField` placeholder's text using:

```
textField.placeholder = "placeholder"
```

Then, as I am using a `UIPickerView` as my `inputView`, when a picker view element is selected I update the `placeholder` by doing `textField.placeholder = nil` and making the `textField.text = "pickerViewValue"`. But the placeholder doesn't clear and there is a slight shadow behind the text as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQzwA.jpg

(You have to look really close to see it. You'll see it says 'Size' super faintly behind the darker L).

I've tried setting the text and `attributedText` as placeholders instead of using the placeholder property, but whenever I do this, the first value set to either text or `attributedText` remain in the background just like the placeholder text did. I've tried setting all these attributes to nil and to "". No dice. Wondering if anyone has had a similar issue.

Had trouble formatting code so here's a pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/pqmtaBeG

The important stuff is in the configure, updatePickerViews, and `extensions` of  ProductView

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
  toolBar.barStyle = .default
  toolBar.isTranslucent = true
  toolBar.tintColor = globalAppleBlue
  toolBar.sizeToFit()

  let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

  let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePickerViewButtonTapped(_:)))
  doneButton.setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)], for: .normal)

  toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
  toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

  let textField = VoraTextField(leftPadding: globalPadding * 1.5, rightPadding: 0.0)
  textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.9)

  textField.placeholder = option.name.capitalized

  let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "right-angle"))
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

  textField.rightView = imageView
  textField.rightViewMode = .always
  textField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
  textField.textColor = .black
  textField.delegate = self

  textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

  let pickerView = UIPickerView()
  self.pickerViewArray.append(pickerView)
  pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
  pickerView.backgroundColor = .white
  textField.inputView = pickerView
  textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect

  pickerView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Please provide code snippets

Comment: Updated! Please let me know if I can add anything else that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's causing the issue but as a workaround try to add solid background color in your textfield.

```
UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1) // changed alpha to 1
```

Of course with that values, the color will be much darker.

Comment: This solved my problem so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer. Feel free to add more answers if you think you can figure out the underlying issue.

Thanks for the speedy response elbert!